# How i get a distinct values from two columns and make it one colunm

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for query that What are the Languages studied by Male Programmers. from the follwing table

```
ID  PNAME    GENDER PROF1     PROF2
 1  ANAND      M    PASCAL    BASIC
 2  ALTAF      M    CLIPPER   COBOL
 3  JULIANA    F    COBOL     DBASE
 4  KAMALA     F    C         DBASE
 5  MARY       F    CPP       ORACLE
 6  NELSON     M    COBOL     DBASE
 7  PATTRICK   M    PASCAL    CLIPPER
 8  QADIR      M    ASSEMBL   C
 9  RAMESH     M    PASCAL    DBASE
 10 REBECCA    F    BASIC     COBOL
 11 REMITHA    F    C         ASSEMB
 12 REVATHI    F    PASCAL    BASIC
 13 VIJAYA     F    FOXFRP    C
```

when used simple query to get out only male programers ,I can use that 
`SELECT [ID], [PNAME],[GENDER],[PROF1],[PROF2] FROM [PRAC].[dbo].[PROGRAMMER] where gender = 'M'`

```
ID  PNAME    GENDER    PROF1    PROF2
 1  ANAND    M         PASCAL   BASIC
 2  ALTAF    M         CLIPPER  COBOL
 6  NELSON   M         COBOL    DBASE
 7  PATTRICK M         PASCAL   CLIPPER
 8  QADIR    M         ASSEMBL  C
 9  RAMESH   M         PASCAL   DBASE
```

even we can get distinct values from both colunms with union command e.g

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROF1 FROM PROGRAMMER WHERE gender = 'M' 
union
SELECT DISTINCT PROF2 FROM PROGRAMMER WHERE gender = 'M'

PROF
---------
ASSEMBL
BASIC
C
CLIPPER
COBOL
DBASE
PASCAL
```

but i want something like that which i dont able to do.

```
ID  PNAME      GENDER   proficiency
1   ANAND       M          PASCAL
1   ANAND       M          BASIC
2   ALTAF       M          CLIPPER
2   ALTAF       M          COBOL
6   NELSON      M          COBOL
6   NELSON      M          DBASE
7   PATTRICK    M          PASCAL
7   PATTRICK    M          CLIPPER
8   QADIR       M          ASSEMBL
8   QADIR       M          C
9   RAMESH      M          PASCAL
9   RAMESH      M          DBASE
```

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Just add ID, PNAME and GENDER to your query?

Comment: As @JamesZ stated, add those columns to the union statements

Comment: Your real problem is that your table is not 3NF: You should have a child table which stores the student-course relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add require columns to union query.

```
   SELECT       [PROF1],
                [ID],
                [PNAME],
                [GENDER]
FROM PROGRAMMER
WHERE gender = 'M'
UNION
SELECT          [PROF2],
                [ID],
                [PNAME],
                [GENDER]
FROM PROGRAMMER
WHERE gender = 'M'
```

Comment: You may want to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`-- depending on whether or you want to deduplicate the results or not.  `UNION` by itself as in this answer will remove duplicate entries, if there were any.